# Glitch when stopping AKOperationGenerator

Tags: audiokit

When I stop a AKOperationGenerator I hear a glitch.

```
binauralGenerator = AKOperationGenerator(numberOfChannels: 2) { _ in
    let bin = SoundEngineer.binaural(left: Binaural.leftFrequency,
                                         right: Binaural.rightFrequency,
                                         amplitude: Isochronic.amplitude*0.67)
    return bin
}

AudioKit.output = binauralGenerator
AudioKit.start()

// This is how I stop
generator.stop()
```

AudioKit 4.0.4 running on iPhone6.